# Custom fiters not added to datagrid object

Tags: datagrid, vmware-clarity

We have a custom filter component in the clarity datagrid. The filtering seems to be working, but it seems like there is something missing as the datagrid object doesn't have any values of the filter.

So far we have tried creating the filter using the (somewhat limited) documentation. Placing the filter on different placing within the datagrid (both inside and outside the column, due to the size of the filter). Setting the value property of the filter (when we don't set the value property in the filter component, the search results aren't filtered)

**HTML**

```
 <clr-dg-filter
    [clrDgFilter]="customFilter"
    [clrDgFilterOpen]="true"
    (clrFilterValue)="('')">
    <custom-filter
        [dataTable]="myDataTable"
        [columnName]="'PseudoStatus'"
        [dataGrid]="myDatagrid"
        [column]="column"
        #customFilter
        class="custom-filter">
    </custom-filter>
 </clr-dg-filter>
```

**FILTER COMPONENT**

```
 constructor(private filterContainer: ClrDatagridFilter) {
      this.filterContainer.setFilter(this);
 }

 public get changes(): Observable<any> {
      return this._changes.asObservable();
 }

 toggleValue(value: string) {
       if (!this.selectedValue[value]) {
            this.selectedValue = {};
       }
       this.selectedValue[value] = !this.selectedValue[value];
       this.selectedValue[value] ? this.selectedCounter++ : this.selectedCounter--;
       this.value = value;

       this.setColumnFilter();
       this._changes.next(true);
  }
```

I would expect that the filter we've set, can be found in the datagrid object - just like the ClrDgStringFilter. Something like this:

```
field: 'filterColumnName'  
filter: DatagridStringFilterImpl  
filterValue: 'set filter value'
```

However, the column in the datagrid object has the following values for its properties:

```
field: undefined  
filter: undefined  
filterValue: [Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at ClrDatagridColumn.get [as filterValue]
```

There are multiple column (without custom filters) with this exception in the filterValue, even if we don't have a custom filter in the datagrid.

Comment: What version of Clarity are you using? Is there any way you can show me a recreation of the issue with a stackblitz?

Comment: We are using Clarity v1.0.5. I have a stackblitz recreation of the filter: [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jppzou). Unfortumately, I couldn't get the TypeError, but the filter issue is there.